# Is "fleabag" as a derogatory term for an unpleasantly dirty person a Britishism?

Tags: word-usage, slang, transatlantic-differences

I have always heard and used "fleabag" as referring to a shabby hotel/motel room, a dump of a place, so I was kind of surprised to see it also has a separate meaning of a dirty person. This usage is not listed in some dictionaries, but does occur in some others.

Google/Lexico:

> 1. A shabby and unpleasant person or thing.
> 2. *NORTH AMERICAN* a seedy, run-down hotel or lodging house.

It is interesting to note that Lexico considers the hotel meaning North American and the other one general usage.

Cambridge, on the other hand, says:

> *UK informal* a dirty and/or unpleasant person or animal
>
> *US* a cheap, dirty hotel

So is the person meaning a BrE. usage? Or was it used as well on this side of the pond at some point?

For reference, "fleabag" doesn't have a separate entry in the OED, but under *flea* it says:

> **flea-bag**  n. *slang* a bed; also, a soldier's sleeping-bag; also applied to a shabby building, place, etc.

Comment: In BE, a dump of a place, is a "flea-**pit**". At its most popular, it was common in reference to cheap cinemas but could apply to almost any place where people [usually, lower class] gathered. I have not heard "flea-bag" used in this sense. Otherwise, a flea-bag is usually a verminous dog, cat or horse and, currently and more rarely, a person.

Comment: If you look at the OED reference, "flea-bag" makes sense as a sleeping bag or bedroll, and likely several of the other senses have derived from that.  A homeless person, eg, would carry around a "flea-bag" bedroll.

Comment: Today Fleabag may refer to the three-season TV series by that name. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleabag

Comment: Pro tip from a frequent Travel.SE participant: It's worth the extra $5 a night to upgrade from a fleabag to a rattrap.

Answer (score 1):

According GDoS the term ***[fleabag](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/uwxzbva)*** has a military origin and its earliest usage instances are Irish:

> 1. (orig. milit., also flea-park) a sleeping bag or bed; a bedroll, a mattress.

> - c.1790  [Ire]   ‘De May-Bush’ in Walsh Ireland Ninety Years Ago (1885) 91: Bill Durham [...] *Was now in his flea-park, taking a snore Fearing every moment the arrival of the real Simon Pure should cover me with shame and disgrace.*

> - 1839    [Ire]   C.J. Lever Harry Lorrequer 266: ‘*I think the gentleman would be better if he went off to his flea-bag himself.’ In my then mystified intellect this west country synonym for a bed a little puzzled me.*

The related meaning  of “a cheap hotel or lodging house” appears to have developed  mainly in the US.

> - 1931    [US]    D. Runyon ‘Broadway Financier’ in Runyon on Broadway (1954) 204: *I will be living at home with her instead of in a flea bag in Forty-seventh Street.*

> - 1946    [US]    Mezzrow & Wolfe Really the Blues 177: *We all laid around that fleabag-with-room-service for a couple of gripy weeks.*

> - 2003    - [US]  N. Green Angel of Montague Street (2004) 3: *There was still a lot of old fleabags like the Hotel Montague.*

From that the term was used to refer to an old dog:

> - 1977    [US]    S. Stallone Paradise Alley (1978) 28: ‘*There ain’t no reason to call Bella a fleabag.’ ‘Hey Vic, that mutt’s got no class.’.*

or a trump, a vagrant:

> - 2001        OnLine Dict. of Playground Sl. [Internet] fleabag n. derog. *smelly person dressed in Oxfam style dress, possibly wearing Tesco trainers, possibly having fleas too.*

Comment: So this seems to suggest the person meaning is rather new, a neologism even?

Comment: @EddieKal - GDoS actually refers to earlier usages for a person mainly as US Black , but its current sense appears to be relatively recent.